# What happens when you put the same reference of the object more than once in a sync.Pool

Tags: go, pool

So I have a simplified version of my code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "sync"
)

var bufferPool = sync.Pool{
    New: func() any {
        return &bytes.Buffer{}
    }
}

func getBuffer() *bytes.Buffer {
    b := bufferPool.Get().(*bytes.Buffer)
    b.Reset()
    return b
}

func releaseBuffer(b *bytes.Buffer) {
    if b != nil {
        b.Reset()
        bufferPool.Put(b)
    }
}

func main() {
    bb := getBuffer()
    defer releaseBuffer(bb)

    processSomething(bb)
    /* Write to the buffer and process some bytes and then... */

    releaseBuffer(bb) // The same buffer is putted in the pool twice

    anotherBuffer := getBuffer()
    anotherAnotherBuffer := getBuffer()
}
```

**So my question is:**

`anotherBuffer` and `anotherAnotherBuffer` are the same object?? points to the same buffer??

I raised this question because of a bug that another goroutine get a buffer from the pool and release it to the pool twice, I don't know if that is the problem

Comment: Yes, if you put the same thing in the pool multiple times, you may get the same thing out multiple times. In your example though you have only put it back in the pool once at that point, the defer has not yet run.